# Create videoplayer shortcode module for drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a custom player I made (Using flowplayer) and would like to make a short code for the id of that player. For example, when the user pastes [myplayer 12345], it will display that player with the appropriate video.

Can anyone point tell me how to do this in drupal?
I know in wordpress it's simple like this:

```
add_shortcode('myplayer','myplayer_video');

    function myplayer_video($attr) {


    $output = '<iframe width="448" height="282" src="http://mysite.com/embed/' . $attr[0] . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe>';

    return $output; 
}
```

My understanding is I need to make a module and I have looked at many tuts on making modules in drupal, but none on how to access the content field and diplay something or php code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the [Custom Filter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter) module.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress shortcodes are implemented as filters, which pretty much have a direct analogue in Drupal, which also happen to be called filters.

If you want to implement this yourself, you could have to create a custom module and then implement [hook_filter_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) in Drupal 7 or [hook_filter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_filter/6) in Drupal 6.

There are also some module, like @Jimajamma mentions that let you do everything from the UI.

You may also want to check out the [Flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer) module to see if it fits your needs.  Normally, though, I either make my own shortcodes or custom field handling, instead of using this module.

Comment: I am wanting to do the custom module route. I looked at the hook_filter_info link. It helps explain things a bit. Still not sure how to implement my code from above.